# Will upgrading from 0.10.2 fix read block errors?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a relatively old version of Bitcoin Core (0.10.2) aka Bitcoin-QT.app, installed in 2015. Bitcoin Core won't open anymore. I'm on MacOS Mohave, v10.14.6. and I have just 60Gb of free hard drive space now. Below is what I've tried and my questions.

**What I've tried**

Tried to open Bitcoin-Qt.app, either through the terminal or the GUI. I goes through the verifying blocks stage. Then it says `Loading wallet...` and there is an error message, `Error: A fatal internal error occured, see debug.log for details`

In `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`, I can see various files including my `wallet.dat`

At the bottom of the debug.log file I see the following:

```
2021-03-07 14:15:02 ERROR: CheckProofOfWork() : nBits below minimum work
2021-03-07 14:15:02 ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk : Errors in block header
2021-03-07 14:15:02 *** Failed to read block
```

**Questions**

- What's going on here? Will this be fixed if I update to Bitcoin Core v0.21.0 (the latest version) given that I'm coming from such an old version (0.10.2)?
- Given I don't have enough hard drive space for the full blockchain size, would I be able to use an external hard rive in the process of upgrading? Bitcoin-Qt.app was initially installed on my MacBook, not an external HD. I know you can use an external drive on install.. but I'm not sure if it's different in an upgrading situation like mine?
- Apart from backing up my `wallet.dat`, is there anything else I should take into consideration.